# event.target[matches] error on form submit in Meteor React project

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, meteor

I am struggling with this bug. Here's my code:

It's long, so here's a short version: I have a form to create an event, I want handleSubmit() to handle error messages and if there are none, add event to db. I do import {Events}, in fact the form worked before I made some changes. When I run it, I get an error message: Uncaught TypeError: event.target[matches] is not a function. Thanks for anyone looking into this.

```
export default class Create extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      error: {}
  }

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  this.setState({error: {}});
  let title = this.refs.title.value;
  if (!title) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = prevState;
      newState.error.title = 'Title has to be filled up.';
      return newState;
    })
  }
  let description = this.refs.description.value;
  if (!description) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = prevState;
      newState.error.description = 'Description has to be filled up.';
      return newState;
    })
  }


  if (!this.state.error) {
      Events.insert({title: title, description: description});
      this.props.history.push('/home');
  }
```

and:

```
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

        <input ref="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"
        style={this.state.error.title ? {borderBottomColor: 'red'} : undefined}/>
        <div className="errorText">{this.state.error.title}</div>

        <input ref="description" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"
        style={this.state.error.description ? {borderBottomColor: 'red'} : undefined}/>
        <div className="errorText">{this.state.error.description}</div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Create new event</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I posted an answer a while ago. It was a false alarm, I am still bugged by this... Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `this.handleSubmit = ...` from the constructor, it's not necessary in order to be able to call this.handleSubmit.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I think I'm getting close though. It's a combination of setState being asynchronous and empty objects being truthy. And the error message comes from a chrome extension. :(

Answer (score 0):

So there are two problems with the code:

1. setState is async. It resolves after the function executes. Workaround: `let error = false` at the beginning and then set `error = true` together with setState call.
2. Empty objects are truthy. Thanks to `error` variable, we can just change the condition to `if(!error)`. Or do `if(error) {return}` - this also works.

Oh, and the error message was from a chrome extension. Sucks that chrome doesn't tell you that an error message came from an extension - at least I don't think it does.

Best,