# error on form submit in React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, meteor

I am struggling with this bug in my Meteor React app.

Long story short: I have a form to create an event, I want handleSubmit() to handle error messages and if there are none, add event to db. I do import {Events}, in fact the form worked before I made some changes. When I run it, I get an error message: Uncaught TypeError: event.target[matches] is not a function. The file that threw the error is unfortunately gibberish to me.

Here's my code:

```
export default class Create extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      error: {}
  }

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  this.setState({error: {}});
  let title = this.refs.title.value;
  if (!title) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = prevState;
      newState.error.title = 'Title has to be filled up.';
      return newState;
    })
  }
  let description = this.refs.description.value;
  if (!description) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = prevState;
      newState.error.description = 'Description has to be filled up.';
      return newState;
 })
}

if (!this.state.error) {
   Events.insert({title: title, description: description});
   this.props.history.push('/home');
}
```

and my html:

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

        <input ref="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"
        style={this.state.error.title ? {borderBottomColor: 'red'} : undefined}/>
        <div className="errorText">{this.state.error.title}</div>

        <input ref="description" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"
        style={this.state.error.description ? {borderBottomColor: 'red'} : undefined}/>
        <div className="errorText">{this.state.error.description}</div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Create new event</button>

    </form>
```

Unfortunately I can't proceed with the project until this error is resolved, so I would be really happy if someone helped me!

Best,

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for taking the time. It is a duplicate. The other one is unaswered... I waited for 30 mins there wasn't a single new view, so I guess it's dead and the question is still relevant. Can you please cancel your downvote, because it is not helping. Best,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like element.matches function is not supported for your targeted element,

I am un clear whether this is caused by meteor native script, as i have not used meteor.

But, you can have a check for this by adding this code and add your own prototype to bypass this error.

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
Element.prototype.matches = 
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i = matches.length;
        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1;            
    };
}
```

[SOURCES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

I hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: Hey Vipul, thanks so much for taking the time. I just discovered the problem and I'm about to post it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967707/event-targetmatches-error-on-form-submit-in-meteor-react-project